# How to Fix Different Type Return in Pandas "np.where"?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this "np.where" in a script a but when it returns the format changes,

How can I fix this? I want a return in datatime.

```
In [22]: new[["DME","Ent. Prog."]]
Out[22]:
            DME Ent. Prog.
0    2021-07-15
1    2021-07-15
...         ...        ...
7481 2021-07-13
7482 2021-07-13

[7483 rows x 2 columns]

In [23]: new["DME"] = np.where(new['Ent. Prog.'] == '', new["DME"],new['Ent. Prog.'])

In [24]: new[["DME","Ent. Prog."]]
Out[24]:
                      DME Ent. Prog.
0     1626307200000000000
1     1626307200000000000
...                   ...        ...
7481  1626134400000000000
7482  1626134400000000000

[7483 rows x 2 columns]


new["DME"] = np.where(new['Ent. Prog.'] == '', new["DME"],new['Ent. Prog.'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is second column is not filled by datetimes, possible solution is convert both columns and test for misisng values:

```
new['DME'] = pd.to_datetime(new['DME'])
new['Ent. Prog.'] = pd.to_datetime(new['Ent. Prog.'])

new["DME"] = np.where(new['Ent. Prog.'].isna(), new["DME"],new['Ent. Prog.'])
```

Or replace missing values by another column in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
new["DME"] = new['Ent. Prog.'].fillna(new['DME'])
```